# (iphone) is it possible to change camera view?

Tags: iphone, view, camera

I'd like to take a sneak picture while user is playing my app and show the pic after a certain time period.

If that's not possible, I'd like to decrease the camera view size.

Is that possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I dont think Apple will allow you to "sneak a pic" of the user. Your app may or may not get rejected, you may want to think of another way to allow the app to take snap of the user, maybe an alert, much like the Location dialog, asking the user to allow the action.

Answer (score 1):

```
     UIImagePicker *imagePicker.cameraViewTransform = 
                                 CGAffineTransformScale(imagePicker.cameraViewTransform,    1.0f, .5f);

You can change the by using this one.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is completely possible. Just have a UIView overlay your UIImagePickerView. Use the 
-takePicture method to randomly take a picture without them pressing anything.

Comment: Can u just explain how it possible?